# Python 3: Launching A Bash Script Within A Python Script

Tags: python, linux, macos, python-3.x, subprocess

I've created a TCP client/server which is used to determine if software is up to date and if it's not it calls a bash script to perform the software upgrade. I have got this to work successfully on Windows using the below code and launching the client from Cygwin

```
subprocess.call("windowsUpgrade.sh", shell=True)
```

However, when I try to use this from a Linux or Mac based client I get the errors

```
/bin/sh: linuxUpgrade.sh: not found
```

and

```
/bin/sh: macUpgrade.sh: command not found
```

Any ideas on what causes this issue and how to resolve it? 
Thanks

Comment: Current working directory differences? Are you certain that those scripts have a hash-bang line at the top? Are in the right location, etc.?

Comment: They do have the hash-bang line at the top (#!/bin/bash) and they are in the same directory as the client which is root on Linux and Desktop on the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current directory is by default not in the PATH variable, where executables were searched for, try:

```
subprocess.call("./linuxUpgrade.sh", shell=True)
```

also, make sure your script is marked as executable

```
chmod u+x linuxUpgrade.sh
```